# Fetching and displaying Data for Each Registered User in PHP using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have been trying to fetch data from the database and display each user's data on their dashboard, but what is giving me is the whole data in the database. I have tried many fetch data functions but some will give me error. I had check round the web and here to see if I can get something close to mine challenge but I have not been able to get any helpful one.

This is my code

```
$sql="SELECT * from users";
$query = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 1)
{
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
```

This is the database structure

[image]

This is the user dashboard. It should return the data according to the username. Any method of fetch I used will return error.

[image]

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `prepare/execute` without placeholders is redundant. `query()` will suffice given no user input.

Answer (score -1):

Have your `SQL` statement query for the columns that you wish your obtain (not sure where your `Date` data is coming from though).

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, username, email FROM users');
$statement->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    // Validate and do something with this data
}
```

Also, make sure your syntax is correct. As your example code is not.

Edit:

As mentioned; if you only want data for a specific user, you need to add filtering clauses to your `SQL` statement.

For example:

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, username, email FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$statement->bindValue('id', $someUserId);
```